# Telerik Rad Button Dyanamically check

Tags: vb.net, telerik

Have been unable to dynamically check a Telerik Rad Button control from the code behind in vb.net code.  I have used things like chk_TypeEmployee.Checked = True with no result.

```
 <telerik:RadButton ID="chk_TypeEmployee" runat="server" ToggleType="Radio" ButtonType="StandardButton"     GroupName="StandardButton" Text="Employee"></telerik:RadButton>
  <telerik:RadButton ID="chk_TypeAgency" runat="server" ToggleType="Radio" ButtonType="StandardButton" GroupName="StandardButton" Text="Agency"></telerik:RadButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ToggleStates`:

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="chk_Type" runat="server" ToggleType="Radio" ButtonType="StandardButton" GroupName="StandardButton" Checked="true">
    <ToggleStates>
        <telerik:RadButtonToggleState Value="Employee" Text="Employee" PrimaryIconCssClass="rbToggleRadioChecked" />
        <telerik:RadButtonToggleState Value="Agency" Text="Agency" PrimaryIconCssClass="rbToggleRadio" />
    </ToggleStates>
</telerik:RadButton>
```

To set dynamicaly the button to "Agency" state, assuming it is the second ToggleState for the button:

```
chk_Type.ToggleStates[0].Selected = false;
chk_Type.ToggleStates[1].Selected = true;
```

Could be rewritten cleaner this way:

```
string DBValue = "Agency";
foreach (RadButtonToggleState state in chk_Type.ToggleStates)
{
    state.Selected = state.Value.Equals(DBValue);
}
```

And to retrieve the selected value, use the `chk_Type.SelectedToggleState.Value`.

Note: The RadButton's property `Checked` must be set to true. And at least 1 of your toggle states should be Selected, else the first toggle state would be selected by default. In order to use more than 2 toggle states, please read about `ToggleType="Custom"`.

Read more about [Telerik's Toggle Buttons](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/button/examples/radiosandcheckboxes/defaultcs.aspx).

Comment: But what would I use to set the toggle state to Agency dynamically, because I tried the ToggleStates and I was not having any success setting them dynamically.  My use case is mutually exclusive radio buttons that can be set dynamically based off of data from the database.  That link does show how to use the code behind to set the value of the radButton

Comment: I was unable to use .Value = "Agency" to render any change in the radio buttons.  Or using .Value = "Employee". Neither created a change in what was displayed visually.

Comment: I can use .Visible = False to hide the telerik control, but I am unable to set the value.  I've also tried using chk_Type.SelectedToggleState.Value = "Employee"

Comment: Whenever I check the value using chk_Type.SelectedToggleState.Value the value in there is properly set, but visibly it is wrong.

Comment: Your RadButton must have the `Checked="true"` property set.

Comment: chk_Type.ToggleStates(0).Selected = True
      chk_Type.ToggleStates(1).Selected = False

Comment: Oh I see...ou were using VB all that time?

Comment: Yields no results and Checked="True" is set on the RadButton

Comment: Yep VB, not my choice though

Comment: `chk_Type.ToggleStates(0).Selected = True` would select the first `ToggleState`, so in your case "Employee".

Comment: That was a bad copy and paste, I have two different case statements.  That was copied from the first case that sets Employee.  I just have copied this case.

Comment: This is the full case statement as it is currently

Comment: chk_Type.SelectedToggleState.Value = "Agency"
                        chk_Type.Value = "Agency"
                        chk_Type.ToggleStates(0).Selected = False
                        chk_Type.ToggleStates(1).Selected = True

Comment: Don't use the `.Value`, since you are now using the `ToggleStates`.

Comment: Employee is checked by default, the dot is filled and Employee css background is dark gray.  When I click on Employee the text changes to light grey and the checkbox is no longer filled.

Comment: I ended up just adding a regular asp radio button control and adding that to the postback.  Something is just acting weird with setting it dynamically. Thanks for your help though!