# How to get telerik radio button state

Tags: c#, telerik, radio-button

How i can get state of radio button telerik component in c# ?

State is checked  or no ?

**I tried this code but its incorrect :**

```
If (radRadiobutton1.togglestate == 1)
{
....
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687545/telerik-rad-button-dyanamically-check

Comment: Telerik radio button dosn't have checked or selected property and my question for the win app programming not web app